# Как с клиента передать в метод на сервере значение параметра типа DateTime?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Есть следующий метод на сервере:

```
public ContentResult GetRequestsInPeriod(DateTime? startOf, DateTime stopOf)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var _startOf = startOf?? new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
    var _stopOf = stopOf?? now.AddDays(1);
    var requests = _requestService.GetRequestsInPeriod(_startOf, _stopOf)
    return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requests), "application/json")
}
```

есть следующее представление:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ReportController">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Параметры отчета:
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h4>Период отчета:</h4>
                        <label>С:</label>
                        <div class="input-group col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" name="startOf" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy" ng-model="startOf" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <label>По:</label>
                        <div class="input-group col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" name="stopOf" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy" ng-model="stopOf" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <input type="button" value="Получить отчет" ng-click="getReport(startOf, stopOf)" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <h3 class="text-center">Простой оборудования по заявкам за период: с {{startOf}} по {{stopOf}}</h3>

        <h4>Отчет выполнил: @Model.ReportInfo.Author</h4>
        <h4>Дата/время получения отчета: @DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm")</h4>

     <!--Здесь таблица для отображения списка заявок-->

    </div>
</div>
```

js код:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngLocale']);

app.controller('ReportController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    var now = new Date();
    $scope.startOf = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 1);
    $scope.stopOf = now.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);

    $scope.getReport = function (startOf, stopOf) {
        console.log(startOf);
        console.log(stopOf);
        var url = '/Report/GetRequestsInPeriod';
        $http.get(url)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.list = { requests: data };
        });    
    };

    $http.get('/Report/GetRequestsInPeriod')
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.list = { requests: data };
        });

    $scope.dateOptions = { startingDay: 1 };

    $scope.open1 = function () {
        $scope.popup1.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.open2 = function () {
        $scope.popup2.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.popup1 = {
        opened: false
    };

    $scope.popup2 = {
        opened: false
    };    
}]);
```

Помогите реализовать метод ***getReport(startOf, stopOf)*** в [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) контролере, если быть точнее то как сформировать `url` что бы на сервер были переданы введенные значения в поле ввода(`startOf`, `stopOf`).

Comment: что-то не вижу чтобы что-то куда-то передавалось

Comment: @Grundy если Ты имеешь ввиду что в `url` который указан в методе `getReport()` отсутствуют параметры, то в этом то и проблема, если бы параметр был типа `int` то я бы сделал так `"/Report/Requests?parameterId="+id`; но как это сделать с `DateTime` в упор не пойму, пробовал так: `"/Report/Requests?startOf=+startOf+"&stopOf="+stopOf`; на сервер приходит `null` в параметрах

Comment: у каждого из методов в `$http` вторым параметром идет config :) в котором можно задать поле data, которое будет передаваться.

Comment: _на сервер приходит null в параметрах_ - это потому, что mvc не может полученные строки сконвертировать в дату. Чтобы он смог шли просто строки в ISO формате например таком: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: Писать `Ты' c большой буквы это круто )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавать дату можно каким угодно способом, весь вопрос заключается в том, как сделать, чтобы MVC смог перевести переданную строку в свою дату.

В качестве вариантов может быть передача секунд в UTC, 
либо перевод даты в строку с таким форматом, чтобы конвертер MVC смог его распознать

Самым простым будет использование формата ISO, его можно собирать вручную, используя фильтр `date`, либо воспользоваться функцией [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

<sub>не совсем понял почему метод возвращает ContentResult, а не JsonResult</sub>

Отправка может выглядеть так:

```
$http.get('url?question='+d.toISOString())
```

Серверная часть так:

```
public JsonResult GetAnswer(DateTime question)
{               
    return Json(new {answer="answer"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

[Пример на dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wjUPO0)

Comment: *не совсем понял почему метод возвращает ContentResult, а не JsonResult* потому что в результате присутствует поле типа `DateTime` который *правильней сериализуется* (хотя может я просто не умею готовить стандартный механизм) при помощи метода `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` `nuget` пакета `Newtonsoft.Json`